# Calling startActivityForResult() inside a fragment doesn't work properly on API 18

Tags: android, android-fragments, onactivityresult, start-activity

I'm using following codes to start an activity for a result inside a fragment.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NextActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.RequestCodes.UPDATE_TIMELINE);
```

The right way is, my fragment must call the activity that I specified and get the result back into `onActivityResult()`. This way is right in Android API 22 but on API 18 the above code instead starting the activity and get the result back, first calls `onActivityResult()` with null data then starts the activity! That's weird!

**Note:** I'm using build tools v23.0.2

**An Example** AActivity has AFragment which the fragment starts BActivity for a result. On API 22 everything is okay but on API 18 the fragment first fires its `onActivityResult()` method and its parent method then starts the activity! And that's the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! From a singleInstance activity cannot start an activity for a result. the solution is using singleTop as the activity launchMode attribute.